# Erro extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

Tags: php-7

Olá, tudo bem?
Estou tentando implementar um sistema web utilizando PHP + apache sem instalador no Windows 10, mas quando vou acessar os dados do DB da o erro "could not find driver" por falta das extensões php_pdo_sqlite.dll e php_pdo.dll. Já descomentei essas linhas e inseri as que faltavam no php.ini, mas as dll não foram instaladas automaticamente na pasta ext.
Já tentei reinstalar o PHP e reiniciar o serviço do apache e nada das dll. Só aparecem as dll que vem junto na instalação para windows na pasta ext.

Tentei baixar as dll e inserir manualmente na ext mas não encontrei nenhuma compatível, o sistema não rodou.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Muito obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Questões de configuração de software, suporte e manutenção de infraestrutura devem ser feitas em inglês no [su] ou [sf] conforme o assunto. Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas de cada comunidade antes de postar lá. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).